# WordPress date query returns false positives

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, date

I have a bit of a complicated `wp_query` going on with a new website, and it's returning some false positives based on the date parameters.

I want users to be able to search events, based on the start and end dates. Each event can have multiple 'periods' that it is running though (a Winter and Summer period, for example).

The periods are set up in an [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) repeater field, so in the database it looks like this:

Period 1: `date_0_start-date` / `date_0_end-date`
Period 2: `date_1_start-date` / `date_1_end-date`
Period 3: `date_2_start-date` / `date_2_end-date`
etc...

If there is only one period, the query works fine. However, if there are multiple periods, events almost always show up, even when they are way out of the users search range.

Here's the wp_query:

```
$args = array(  
    // general
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,

    'meta_key' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-key'],
    'orderby' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-by'],
    'order' => 'ASC',

    // category filter
    'tax_query' => $taxQuery,

    // date filter
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
            'value' => $when,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
            'value' => $when2,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )


);
```

I also have these functions being added before the query to change it slightly to allow the `%` in the query to be variable:

```
function date_to( $to ) {
    $to = str_replace("mt1.meta_key = 'date_%_end-date'", "mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date'", $to);
    return $to;
}

function date_from( $from ) {
    $from = str_replace("meta_key = 'date_%_start-date'", "meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date'", $from);
    return $from;
}
```

However, it doesn't check that the `%` variable matches up, so it can get the start date from period 1 and the end date from period 2 and make it match the users query.

Any ideas how I can refine this to make it more robust to multiple periods?

[EDIT]
SQL Query as requested in comments.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND wp_posts.ID 
IN (1033,1039, ... more numbers ... 1264) 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20131201')
AND  (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20150101') ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY FIELD( wp_posts.ID, 1033,1039, ... more numbers ... 1264 ) 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

[EDIT]

Updated code based on the answers below, still not quite working though.

New function:

```
function add_additional_where_condition( $wp_query) {
    $wp_query = str_replace("WHERE", "WHERE substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6) AND ", $wp_query);
    return $wp_query;
}
```

Being added with: 
`add_filter('posts_where', 'add_additional_where_condition');`

SQL Returned:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 
ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 
ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID IN (503,475,529,473,469) 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date'
AND  (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20140611')
AND  (mt2.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20140618') ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value 
ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: rtm about special symbols in `LIKE` pattern. afaik `_` mean any symbol, so it must be escaped `\_`. p.s. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Hi, just tried changing it to `mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_\__end-date'` etc. but it returned no results instead. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Show us database dump and real query.

Comment: Can you provide the full query and schema?

Comment: tried to answer but the more I think about your question afterwards, the higher the chance my answer might be wrong. Got to agree with the others, unless you show the full query and table, it's hard to help. But I have a feeling you don't need LIKE.

Comment: Hi, will add the final SQL query to the post.

Comment: What's in `$when & $when2` ? I mean `Date` Or `Time`. See My Answer and change `type`...

Comment: `$when` is the start date (format YYYYMMDD) and `$when2` is the end date, same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is not easy to achieve.

What you need is something like:

```
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_start-date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20131201')
AND  (mt1.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_end-date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20150101') ) 

AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6)
```

So the right start date will be used with the correct end date.

You could include an additional function that will add this condition at the beginning of the WHERE clause:

```
function add_additional_where_condition( $where) {
    $where .= " AND substr(wp_postmeta.meta_key, 1, 6) = substr(mt1.meta_key, 1, 6) ";
    return $where;
}
```

The two `substr()` should return the same `date_#` value.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like the right kind of thing to me, but adding the function didn't actually change anything for me :/ Should it be changing the `WHERE 1=1 ` line?

Comment: doesn't it change the SQL generated? do you call this new function like you call `date_to` and `date_from`? changing the `1=1` will have the same effect, I changed `WHERE` just to be sure that the other parts of the query were the same.

Comment: Nope, didn't change it at all for some reason. Yep, I called it in exactly the same way, very weird.

Comment: just noticed that I was returning `$query`, but the modified query was assigned to a variable with a different name. Let me know if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi, just tried this, but still no luck. Will update the question with the code I have now.

Comment: @lukeseager ok, I tried to reply without really checking the WP documentation, add_filter('posts_where', 'some_function') allows you to work with the where condition. I tried to replace directly WHERE, not very smart. I have changed my function, it should work now. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Comment: Amazing! It feels like it's getting there, the change has showed up, but I'm getting this error: `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause']`

Comment: Just noticed it was actually doing it though, if I turn wordpress Debug off, the error goes and I'm given the correct results.

Comment: great, it was a good excuse for me to learn something about wordpress :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `type` in `meta_query`.

[Documents](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) Says:-

```
type (string) -> Custom field type.

Possible values are:- 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME',
'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.
```

so try following code:-

```
'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
                    'value' => $when,
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array (
                    'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
                    'value' => $when2,
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
            )
    )
```

Try to change `type` value **`(eg. Date)`** according to your **`Custom Fild type`**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, just tried this, didn't work unfortunately. I think the issue is more with the SQL query not knowing the difference between `date_0_start-date` and `date_1_start-date`

Comment: you have to specify `key`. Or User Manual Query.

Comment: I have specified a key, it's in the original post?

Comment: I mean, Specify in Query Arguments.